How to get available data in a pipe in linux
In Linux, after writing some data in a pipe (yet not read), when using fstat on read/write side of a pipe, the st_size field is zero. Is it possible to get the size of data available in a pipe?
Sample code:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define BUFLEN  8

int main() {
        char            buf[BUFLEN];
        int             fd[2];
        struct stat     sb;

        pipe(fd);

        write(fd[1], buf, BUFLEN);

        fstat(fd[1], &sb);                        // the same for fd[0]

        printf("pipe size=%ld\n", sb.st_size);    // print 0


        exit(0);
}


No, there is no way to know how much data it will eventually contain. The OS will block at some point if the writer fills up the available buffers.

Once upon an aeon ago, I worked on a system where fstat() gave the information (ICL Perq running PNX, to be specific).  Once I switched to other Unix variants (an aeon minus about three years ago), I was disappointed to find that it didn't work on those machines.

Man page  pipe(7) says the following:

   The following ioctl(2) operation, which can be applied to a file
   descriptor that refers to either end of a pipe, places a count of
   the number of unread bytes in the pipe in the int buffer pointed
   to by the final argument of the call:

       ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &nbytes);

   The FIONREAD operation is not specified in any standard, but is
   provided on many implementations.


So some systems have non-standard ioctl operation for getting the number of unread bytes in the pipe.
